# Parse JSON YQL Output with jQuery append to IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

I have a YQL output JSON string at this URL: [YQL JSON](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/current-advisory/%22%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22content%22%5D/div%5B1%5D%27&format=json&callback=cbfunc)

I found some other

I am trying to understand why I cannot get certain items out of the JSON return. For example, using jQuery, if I want the first DIVs H1 I use:

```
$.ajax({
       url:"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.missoulaavalanche.org%2Fcurrent-advisory%2F%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22content%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B1%5D'&format=json",
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp: 'callback',
       jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc'
    });
    function cbfunc(data){
      var id = data.query.results.div;

      $('#table').append('<li>'+id.h1+'</li>');

  $('#table').listview('refresh');
}
```

I have tried to get some info, say the img alt or img src, from the second div... div[1](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/current-advisory/%22%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22content%22%5D/div%5B1%5D%27&format=json&callback=cbfunc) like so:

```
function cbfunc(data){
      var id = data.query.results.div[1];

      $('#table').append('<li>'+id.img.alt+'</li>');

      $('#table').listview('refresh');
    }
```

I keep getting Undefined or no results... What I am missing or not understanding about getting results from the yql JSON list?

EDIT: I read a post on the [YQL Blog about Cache busting](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2010/03/12/avoiding-rate-limits-and-getting-banned-in-yql-and-pipes-caching-is-your-friend/)... So I am using their suggestion there.

EDIT 2: here is the JSON from the yql. I would like to get div img src for example, but am not getting a return or I get an object. I think it would be data.query.results.div[1](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/current-advisory/%22%20and%20xpath=%27//div%5B@id=%22content%22%5D/div%5B1%5D%27&format=json&callback=cbfunc).img.src

I get data.query.results.div.h1 no problem:

```
cbfunc({
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2012-03-28T15:36:28Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "div": {
    "id": "content",
    "div": [
     {
      "class": "post-2491 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-advisories",
      "id": "post-2491",
      "h1": "March 26, 2012 Avalanche Advisory",
      "p": {
       "class": "postmetadata alt",
       "small": {
        "br": [
         null,
         null
        ],
        "a": {
         "href": "http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/category/advisories/",
         "rel": "category tag",
         "title": "View all posts in Advisories",
         "content": "Advisories"
        },
        "content": "This entry was posted on Monday, March 26th, 2012 at 6:55 am\n Categories: \n"
       }
      },
      "div": [
       {
        "id": "danger_rating",
        "a": {
         "href": "http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/wp-content/themes/missoula-avalanche/images/ratings/avalanche_danger_scale.jpg",
         "img": {
          "alt": "Current Danger Rating is MODERATE",
          "src": "http://www.missoulaavalanche.org/wp-content/themes/missoula-avalanche/images/ratings/moderate.gif"
         }
        }
       },
       {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you think if you use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.missoulaavalanche.org%2Fcurrent-advisory%2F%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22content%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B1%5D'&format=json",
          function(data) {
              var id = data.query.results.div;
              $('#table').append('<li>'+id.h1+'</li>');
              $('#table').listview('refresh');
          }
);
```

Comment: Hi swook. Thanks for the response. Will i have issues with YQL caching and this example? Also, I cannot seem to get more than the first DIV results... same as what i already have. I would like to get the second div results and grab the img.src out of there.

Answer (score 2):

The jsonp function option is just define the function name server uses for the wrapper for jsonp.

To access your data you need to do it in success callback of `$.ajax`. Your code above is missing the `$` before `.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.missoulaavalanche.org%2Fcurrent-advisory%2F%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22content%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B1%5D'&format=json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
    success: function(data) {
        var results=data.query.results;
        /* work with results object here*/

    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I see what you are doing there for sure. However, I am still not getting the div[1] information. For example. I would like to get data.query.results.div[1].img.src... I can get data.query.results.div.h1 no problem, but anything on the next div's I am having trouble with. Thanks

Comment: data doesn't appear to be consistent... 1st div has no `img.src` in example response you posted. You may need to fine tune your YQL query